# Alternatives of MQJExplorer tool for capturing request and sending response

Tags: ibm-mq, message-queue, mq

I have an application which uses IBM MQ to send out the request in a queue manager to a particular `system B`.
The response corresponding to that request is then received back from `system B` by the application in a sync call and then further business processing happens.

Since we are working on the offshore region, we do not actually send out the request to `system B` but rather capture it ourselves using the `MQJExplorer` tool and send back the response, which kind of simulates the prod. behaviour.

The problem here is, or i would say, the overhead is that we have to manually open the mqjexplorer tool, check the request, take a particular attribute from the request(lets say `ID`), and send back `ID+1` so that the application recognizes the response is for `ID-1` request.

I would like to know if this particular thing can be automated, with some other tool, where i can define like whenever any such kind of request is received in for eg: `MQ001` queue manager and its `REQ` queue, just extract the `ID` attribute, do a `ID+1` and send back the response in `RESP` queue of same qm.

Answer (score 1):

There are a pair of IBM supplied samples that come with IBM MQ:-

- `amqsreq0.c` - Sample C program that puts request messages to a message queue and shows the replies (example using REPLY queue)
- `amqsecha.c` - Sample C program - echo messages to reply to queue

They are supplied to allow you to try out a request/reply application.

You already have the equivalent app to do the job that `amqsreq0.c` does, and you could adapt `amqsecha.c` to extract your `ID` attribute, increment it, and then the sample already has the code to send the reply back.

It can be automated by running as a triggered application too.

Answer (score 0):

If 'C' language is not your thing and prefer Java then have a read of a [blog posting](https://www.capitalware.com/rl_blog/?p=4587) I did in 2017.   It is a complete request/reply scenario with 2 applications: BEServer01.java and RQClient01.java

You can modify BEServer01.java to your liking (and remove the SQL code).  BEServer01.java contains all of the code for getting a request message and sending a reply message.  Simply replace the variable 'replyText' contents with the reply message that you want.

If you are not a programmer then there is another option but it does not modify the message contents.  [MQ Visual Edit](https://capitalware.com/mqve_overview.html) has a component called: SIM Server.  Its purpose is to simulate a server-side component.  You configure what 'request' queue to get the messages from and what the reply message text will be.  When a messages lands on the request queue, the SIM Server will retrieve it and send the reply message to the queue & queue manager specified in the MQMD's ReplyToQueueName and ReplyToQueueManagerName fields.